# Typedef with and without struct name

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I saw the following oddity in the XCB API header. Most types are defined with a type alias and a struct name in this way:

```
typedef struct xcb_window_iterator_t {
    xcb_window_t *data;
    int rem;
    int index;
} xcb_window_iterator_t;
```

But some typedefs omit the struct name.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int sequence;
} xcb_void_cookie_t;
```

What does this mean from the C point of view?

Is the latter a type with a name and a struct without a name? Or is it no type but only a struct with a name?

My confusion comes from the output of the `gccxml`.

For `xcb_window_iterator_t` it generates a `Struct` node:

```
$ xmllint --format --xpath '//Struct[@name="xcb_window_iterator_t"]' xcb.xml 
<Struct id="_199" name="xcb_window_iterator_t" context="_1" mangled="21xcb_window_iterator_t" demangled="xcb_window_iterator_t" location="f0:43" file="f0" line="43" artificial="1" size="128" align="64" members="_2240 _2241 _2242 _2243 _2244 _2245 _2246 " bases=""/>
```

and a `Typedef` node:

```
$ xmllint --format --xpath '//Typedef[@name="xcb_window_iterator_t"]' xcb.xml 
<Typedef id="_200" name="xcb_window_iterator_t" type="_199" context="_1" location="f0:47" file="f0" line="47"/>
```

But for `xcb_void_cookie_t` it generates just a `Struct` node:

```
$ xmllint --format --xpath '//Struct[@name="xcb_void_cookie_t"]' xcb.xml 
<Struct id="_967" name="xcb_void_cookie_t" context="_1" mangled="17xcb_void_cookie_t" demangled="xcb_void_cookie_t" location="f14:189" file="f14" line="189" size="32" align="32" members="_3655 _3656 _3657 _3658 _3659 " bases=""/>
```

But no `Typedef` node:

```
$ xmllint --format --xpath '//Typedef[@name="xcb_void_cookie_t"]' xcb.xml 
XPath set is empty
```

Does this mean `xcb_void_cookie_t` is no type but just a struct, although the code contains the `typedef`? Or is it a bug in `gccxml`?

Comment: You shouldn't bother at all with typedefs for structs. They are useless. They only save you typing "struct" here and there but obfuscate that something is a struct and needs to be operated on with `.` or `->`.

Comment: @Jens: that's one view — held by respected programmers.  It is not the only view — other respected programmers prefer the alternative.

Answer (score 4):

The 1st snippet defines two types:

- `struct xcb_window_iterator_t`
- `xcb_window_iterator_t`

the latter one:

- `xcb_void_cookie_t`

> Is the lat[t]er a type with a name and a struct without a name

Yes, the `typedef` defines an ["unnamed" (or "anonymous") structure](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Unnamed-Fields.html)

```
struct
{
  unsigned int sequence;
}
```

as the type `xcb_void_cookie_t`.

Comment: Then GCCXML is buggy, because it reports a named struct and no typedef? The right would be a struct with no name and a typedef with name.

Answer (score 1):

If you have

```
typedef struct structname {
   ..
} typename;
```

you can write this to declare a variable `a`:

```
struct structname a;
```

or

```
typename a;
```

---

If you have

```
typedef struct {
   ..
} typename;
```

you can only write this to declare a variable `a`:

```
typename a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The name after the `struct` keyword is optional.  In the context of a `typedef`, that means an instance of the struct can only be declared with the given `typedef`.

In the case of the first `typedef`, you can declare a variable of this type in either of these ways:

- `struct xcb_window_iterator_t var`
- `xcb_window_iterator_t var`.

In the latter case, a variable of that type must be declared as:

- `xcb_void_cookie_t var`